# SQL SERVER base de datos ( Sospechoso )

Tags: sql-server

Uso Microsoft Server Management Studio para conectarme al servidor SQL SERVER y estaba haciendo un Update en una tabla de una base de datos. Durante el proceso como veia que tardaba le di al boton de "cancelar consulta en ejecucion". Entonces se me desconecto el servidor y al volver a entrar la base de datos me aparecia con la etiqueta ( En recuperacion ) y al rato en estado ( Sospechoso ) por lo tanto la base de datos es inaccesible.

¿ como puedo acceder ahora a la base de datos ? ¿ Si pudiera acceder a la tabla que estaba haciendo el update y borrarla alomejor podria volver a trabajar con la base de datos ?

Comment: googlea sqlserver suspect... hay varias formas dependiendo que haya pasado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final conseguí recuperar la base datos, el problema creo que fue porque no tenia casi espacio en el disco duro.

Probe con estas sentencias:

- Para ver el estado de la base de datos

  SELECT name, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (name, N'STATUS') AS N'Status' FROM master.sys.databases
- Y luego probamos con

  EXEC SP_RESETSTATUS  [Base de Datos]

  ALTER DATABASE [Base de Datos] SET EMERGENCY

  DBCC CHECKDB ([Base de Datos])

  ALTER DATABASE [Base de Datos] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

  DBCC CHECKDB ([Base de Datos], REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)

  ALTER DATABASE [Base de Datos] SET MULTI_USER

Answer (score 0):

Para reparar la base de datos ejecuta estas consultas:

```
ALTER DATABASE nombre_base_datos SET EMERGENCY;
ALTER DATABASE nombre_base_datos SET SINGLE_USER;
DBCC CHECKDB (nombre_base_datos, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS);
ALTER DATABASE nombre_base_datos SET MULTI_USER;
```

Comment: Esta es la última opción que se debe utilizar. Literalmente estás diciendo que se puede perder información con tal de tener la base de datos accesible. Lo más interesante sería saber que se pierde y como recuperarlo.

Comment: @LuisCazares por eso es importante los respaldos, si fuera una base de datos de una empresa, sería poco creible que no se realicen respaldos, en caso que algunos datos no se recuperen se tiene el respaldo a mano

Comment: Pero en ese caso, es mejor restaurar los respaldos de datos y log. Es probable que se solucione de una mejor manera y sin necesidad de generar la pérdida de datos. Aunque también conozco muchas empresas que no manejan correctamente sus respaldos.

Comment: La idea es recuperar la base de datos a ser posible con la minima perdida de informacion.

Comment: No funciona  en la linea DBCC CHECKDB ya que me indica "No se procesó la instrucción de reparación. No se permite este nivel de reparación cuando la base de datos está en modo de emergencia."